# Обязательно ли переводить содержимое <string-array> для каждой локали?

Tags: java, android, массивы, строки, locale

Есть файл strigs.xml и 2 локали **RU** (strigs.xml - ru) и **ENG** (strigs.xml -en)
и 2 массива: **Название формулы** и **математическая формула**

Содержимое strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="formulaName">
<item>Formula 1A</item>
<item>Formula 2B</item>
<item>Formula 3C</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="formula">
<item>1A + 2B</item>
<item>2B + 3C</item>
<item>3C + 4D</item>
</string-array>
```

Содержимое strings.xml **(RU)**:

```
<string-array name="formulaName">
<item>Формула 1A</item>
<item>Формула 2B</item>
<item>Формула 3C</item>
</string-array>
```

Содержимое strings.xml **(EU)**:

```
<string-array name="formulaName">
<item>Formula 1A</item>
<item>Formula 2B</item>
<item>Formula 3C</item>
</string-array>
```

Обязательно ли переводить **string-array name="formula"** для каждой локали (или его можно оставить только в основном strings.xml) если данные в массиве будут одинаковы для всех локалей? (

С обычными строками разобрался, можно использовать translatable="false", а про локализацию массивов не могу понять...

Comment: там также можно использовать translatable="false". А какой у вас основной язык?

Comment: Основной английский. А в string-array name="formula" там математические" формулы. Обязательно ли переводить string-array name="formula" (математические формулы) если они на всех локалях будут одинаковы. Или можно массив с формулами оставить только в основном Strings.xml

Comment: не обязательно .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что помимо `string (ru)` и `string (en)` у вас есть просто `string`. Так вот если стоит русская локаль, а в `string (ru)` отсутствует `formula`, то `formula` будет браться из `string`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно по вопросу - вы можете не переводить `formula`, а просто нигде его не записывать кроме первоначальных/дефолтных `string`

---

Так же если вам нужно перевести только 1 элемент массива, или возникли проблемы с переводом массива, то тогда массив стоит записать так

```
<string-array name="array_example1">
    <item>@string/resOne</item>
    <item>@string/resTwo</item>
    <item>@string/resThree</item>
</string-array>
```

И добавить по локалям строки

```
<string name="resOne">One</string>
<string name="resTwo">Two</string>
<string name="resThree">Three</string>
```